# Backbone.js event handler not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling

I was trying the backbone.js examples given [here](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/1.html) and then tried writing some code on my own.

For some reason the event handler I have attached to event 'click p' is not working. Why is the 'highlight' function not executing when a paragraph tag is clicked?

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'p',

    events: {
        'click p': 'highlight'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("An object of ItemView was created");
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'highlight');

        this.render();   
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.text(this.model.get('content'));
        $('body').append(this.$el);
        return this;
    },

    highlight: function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *event* it targeting any `<p>` element inside your *root* element. It is not targeting your *root* element, even if your *root* element is a `<p>` element.

Try:

```
events: {
  'click': 'highlight'
}
```

To target the *root* element.

Comment: However, if I add a `span` inside the <p> tag and then target that `span`, it works.

Comment: Also, one more question: When I use event handlers in a model, can I attach events to the **entire** DOM or only to the elements _inside_ the _root_?

Comment: @Jatin: Are you trying to put a `<p>` inside a `<p>`?

Comment: @muistooshort I was trying to highlight the `<p>` tag when I click it.

Comment: @muistooshort Also could you answer my question in the second last comment? which is: `Also, one more question: When I use event handlers in a model, can I attach events to the entire DOM or only to the elements inside the root?`

Comment: @Jatin: But which `<p>` tag? The view's `el` or a `<p>` inside that? You can't use the view's `events` on things outside its `el` but you can manually bind handlers using normal jQuery means, you'll have to properly clean them up when the view is removed of course.

Comment: @muistooshort The view's `el`.

Comment: @Jatin: Then fguillen's solution works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZYyCm/

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, it works in the jsfiddle! I will try it again in my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... in your render, you replace all the body content with this.$el. I'm thinking you've effectively "unhooked" the events hash when you replace all the content. So after you do the append, call this.delegateEvents() like so:

```
render: function(){
    this.$el.text(this.model.get('content'));
    $('body').append(this.$el);
    this.delegateEvents();
    return this;
}
```

This should allow you to click on your paragraph tags.

Comment: You said, `" in your render, you replace all the body content with this.$el"` No! I didn't do that!